# Adding adapter with html content for axis labels on category axis of amcharts is causing flickering on the chart

Tags: amcharts5

I have use case where I need custom labels on the axis, And as per [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/html-content/#Axis_labels) we need to use adapters for that.

So when I tried using adapters(with html as key) on the category axis it is causing the chart to flicker.

Reproduction steps:

- Go to the [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/) link
- open it in either code pen or jsFiddle which is shown in [image]
- Then in the Js file add the highlighted code in grey for the adapter usage as shown in image.
  [image: code snippet]

Now you can see that the chart is flickering.

Please help on the issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. It seems that rotating labels is not possible when using the html property but similar end result can be achieved by adding some style to html snippet.

Modify the example by changing the xRenderer label config as follows:

```
xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
  paddingTop: 15,
});
```

Add label adapter:

```
xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.adapters.add("html", function(html, target) {
  return '<div style="writing-mode:vertical-rl; text-orientation: sideways; transform: rotate(180deg)">{country}</div>';
});
```

Full example of chart configuration based on the [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/):

```
// Create root element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
  panX: true,
  panY: true,
  wheelX: "panX",
  wheelY: "zoomX",
  pinchZoomX: true
}));

// Add cursor
var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}));
cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);


// Create axes
var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { minGridDistance: 30 });
xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
  paddingTop: 15,
});

xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
  location: 1
})

var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
  maxDeviation: 0.3,
  categoryField: "country",
  renderer: xRenderer,
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.adapters.add("html", function(html, target) {
  return '<div style="writing-mode:vertical-rl; text-orientation: sideways; transform: rotate(180deg)">{country}</div>';
});

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  maxDeviation: 0.3,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
    strokeOpacity: 0.1
  })
}));


// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
  name: "Series 1",
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: yAxis,
  valueYField: "value",
  sequencedInterpolation: true,
  categoryXField: "country",
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText: "{valueY}"
  })
}));

series.columns.template.setAll({ cornerRadiusTL: 5, cornerRadiusTR: 5, strokeOpacity: 0 });
series.columns.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});

series.columns.template.adapters.add("stroke", function(stroke, target) {
  return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});


// Set data
var data = [{
  country: "USA",
  value: 2025
}, {
  country: "China",
  value: 1882
}, {
  country: "Japan",
  value: 1809
}, {
  country: "Germany",
  value: 1322
}, {
  country: "UK",
  value: 1122
}, {
  country: "France",
  value: 1114
}, {
  country: "India",
  value: 984
}, {
  country: "Spain",
  value: 711
}, {
  country: "Netherlands",
  value: 665
}, {
  country: "South Korea",
  value: 443
}, {
  country: "Canada",
  value: 441
}];

xAxis.data.setAll(data);
series.data.setAll(data);


// Make stuff animate on load
series.appear(1000);
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```